# Cartesian Product over Symmetric Difference

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let's say I have that $(x,y)\in (A\times B)\Delta (A\times C).$ How would I expand this statement assuming $A\Delta B = (A-B)\cup (B-A)$?

Here is as far as I have gotten. Let $(x,y)\in (A\times B)\Delta (A\times C).$ Since we define $A\Delta B = (A-B)\cup (B-A)$, then $(A\times B)\Delta (A\times C) = [(A\times B)-(A\times C)]\cup [(A\times C)-(A\times B)].$

Is the next step ($x\in A\times B$ and $x\notin A\times C$) or ($x\in A\times C$ and $x\notin A\times B$)? Wouldn't this produce a contradiction where $x\in A$ and $x\notin A$?

Answer (score 1):

We can simplify further to get

\begin{align}
(A\times B)\Delta (A\times C) & = [(A\times B)-(A\times C)]\cup [(A\times C)-(A\times B)] \\
& = [A \times (B-C)] \cup [A\times (C-B)]\\
& = A \times [(B-C) \cup (C-B)] \\
& = A\times (B\Delta C)
\end{align}

So $(x,y)\in (A\times B)\Delta (A\times C)$ implies $x\in A$ and $y\in B\Delta C$.

Answer (score 0):

**Tony** has given a fine algebraic solution. For a more intuitive approach to exactly the same thing it’s useful to understand a fundamental fact about the symmetric difference of two sets: $X\mathop{\triangle}Y$ is the set of things that belong to exactly one of the sets $X$ and $Y$.

Thus, $\langle x,y\rangle\in(A\times B)\mathop{\triangle}(A\times C)$ if and only if $\langle x,y\rangle$ belongs to exactly one of $A\times B$ and $A\times C$. Clearly this cannot be the case if $x\notin A$, so we can immediately conclude that $x\in A$. Then $\langle x,y\rangle\in A\times B$ if and only if $y\in B$, and $\langle x,y\rangle\in A\times C$ if and only if $y\in C$, so $\langle x,y\rangle$ is in exactly one of $A\times B$ and $A\times C$ if and only if $y$ is in exactly one of $B$ and $C$, i.e., if and only if $y\in B\mathop{\triangle}C$.